# Python: How to pack different types of data into a string buffer using struct.pack_into

Tags: python, c, struct

I'm trying to pack some unsigned int data into a string buffer created using `ctypes.create_string_buffer`.

Here is the following code segment, and a running example showing the error [on codepad](http://codepad.org/S8nUWMcW):

```
import struct
import ctypes
import binascii

buf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(16)
struct.pack_into("=I=I=I", buf, 0, 1, 2, 3)
print binascii.hexlify(buf)
```

This yields the following error:

```
...
struct.error: bad char in struct format
```

The documentation doesn't allude to whether you can pack data of different types if the underlying buffer is of a specific C type. In this case, trying to pack unsigned int data into a string buffer with an underlying c_char type. Anyone know of a solution to do this, or is there a specific way to create a buffer that can pack any type of data?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're not supposed to prefix every output specifier with the '=' code. Just say it once:

```
struct.pack_into("=III", buf, 0, 1, 2, 3)
```

This yields:

```
01000000020000000300000000000000
```

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I missed that critical piece of reading in the module docco :).

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for resurrecting old topic, but I get the point of "snap" - being hit by probably similar background habit.

"the first character of the format string can be used to indicate the byte order, size and alignment of the packed data" I agree. However:

- Python docs deliberately (?) omit even a single example of use of order formatters (*All examples assume a native byte order, size, and alignment with a big-endian machine.*)
- One may assume (as I and *probably* snap did), that "`III`" consists of three format strings and we may format every one of them at will. Hence `=I=I=I`. I shot myself in the foot after getting used to Ruby's array.pack, where one may freely change ordering along the expression (Ruby's equivalent is `I_I_I_` in this case, as order selector comes after type).

Hence I guess it might be good to add a few lines to struct.pack/unpack docs, giving examples of order & padding use (meh, padding hit me even harder... I could live with native order, but padding ruined my protocol).

Comment: If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Comment: It is not a _NEW_ question. After seeing this post I resolved my problem. It is _just_ a note, that Python docs is unclear - for example for people from Ruby world - at this topic.

Comment: I understand, but Stackoverflow is not actually a forum with *topics/threads*, but rather a Q & A site...

Comment: It is fine to answer old questions with new and/or better information.  [so] is not a forum, so you are not reviving an old "topic."

Answer (score 1):

Standard operating procedure: *Read the error message.*

"bad char in struct format" means what it says.

Standard operating procedure: *Check the docs*. [Here](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) it says "the *first* [my emphasis] character of the format string can be used to indicate the byte order, size and alignment of the packed data" and goes on to list `=` as a possibility. The next section (Format Characters) lists many *letters* including `I`.

Conclusion: your format string should be `"=III"`.

Note: The problem has nothing to do with the destination buffer at all, let alone its underlying C type:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack("=I=I=I", 1, 2, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
struct.error: bad char in struct format
>>> struct.pack("=III", 1, 2, 3)
'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00'
>>>
```

Comment: I actually don't think that's a very good error message. It doesn't tell you which character is "bad", and in fact the "bad" character is actually a permissible character (it just happens to only be valid at the beginning of the string).