# Python, how to put 32-bit integer into byte array

Tags: python

I usually perform things like this in C++, but I'm using python to write a quick script and I've run into a wall.

If I have a binary list (or whatever python stores the result of an "fread" in).  I can access the individual bytes in it with: buffer[0], buffer[1], etc.

I need to change the bytes [8-11] to hold a new 32-bit file-size (read: there's already a filesize there, I need to update it).  In C++ I would just get a pointer to the location and cast it to store the integer, but with python I suddenly realized I have no idea how to do something like this.

How can I update 4 bytes in my buffer at a specific location to hold the value of an integer in python?

**EDIT**

I'm going to add more because I can't seem to figure it out from the solutions (though I can see they're on the right track).

First of all, I'm on python 2.4 (and can't upgrade, big corporation servers) - so that apparently limits my options.  Sorry for not mentioning that earlier, I wasn't aware it had so many less features.

Secondly, let's make this ultra-simple.

Lets say I have a binary file named 'myfile.binary' with the five-byte contents '4C53535353' in hex - this equates to the ascii representations for letters "L and 4xS" being alone in the file.

If I do:

```
f = open('myfile.binary', 'rb')
contents = f.read(5)
```

contents should (from Sven Marnach's answer) hold a five-byte immutable string.

Using Python 2.4 facilities only, how could I change the 4 S's held in 'contents' to an arbitrary integer value? I.e. give me a line of code that can make byte indices contents [1-4] contain the 32-bit integer 'myint' with value 12345678910.

Comment: You cannot change the contents since the string is immutable ... you can create a new string, or use a mutable container like bytearray.

Comment: Thanks, I'm happy to create a new string or byte array if that's the case.  How could I create a modifiable byte array with the same contnets, and update the range [1-4] of that to equal the binary representation of my integer?

Comment: I extended my posting below and included a working example for Python 2.4 :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you need is this function:

```
struct.pack_into(fmt, buffer, offset, v1, v2, ...)
```

It's documented at http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html near the top.

Example code:

```
import struct
import ctypes

data=ctypes.create_string_buffer(10)
struct.pack_into(">i", data, 5, 0x12345678)
print list(data)
```

**Similar posting:** [Python: How to pack different types of data into a string buffer using struct.pack_into](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5961407/589206)

**EDIT:** Added a Python 2.4 compatible example:

```
import struct

f=open('myfile.binary', 'rb')
contents=f.read(5)
data=list(contents)
data[0:4]=struct.pack(">i", 0x12345678)
print data
```

Comment: +1. I'd suggest to use the built-in `bytearray` to create the mutable buffer instead of `ctypes.create_string_buffer`.

Comment: **For everyone** I tried working it out by reading the pack page and the solutions provided.  I seem to be missing alot since I have python 2.4 instead of 2.5. I provided a greatly simplified version of my problem in an edit to my post above - if you can answer that with a line of code, I'll be completely happy :)

Comment: I'm afraid your 2.4 compatible version can't use `bytearray` as it was introduced in 2.6.

Comment: Hmmm. That's true, I only avoided the pack_into function ... embarassing. Let's see what was there in 2.4 :)

Comment: Ok I think now it works, tried it on a VM with Python 2.4. Other objections?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module. You need `pack` function.

EDIT:

The code:

```
import struct

s = "LSSSS" # your string
s = s[0] + struct.pack('<I', 1234567891) # note "shorter" constant than in your example
print s
```

Output:

```
L╙☻ЦI
```

`struct.pack` should be available in Python2.4.

Your number "12345678910" cannot be packed into 4 bytes, I shortened it a bit.

Comment: *see comment on hochl's answer*

Answer (score 2):

The result of `file.read()` is a string in Python, and it is immutable.  Depending on the context of the task you are trying to accomplish, there are different solutions to the problem.

One is using the [`array` module](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html): Read the file directly as an array of 32-bit integers.  You can modify this array and write it back to the file.

```
with open("filename") as f:
    f.seek(0, 2)
    size = f.tell()
    f.seek(0)
    data = array.array("i")
    assert data.itemsize == 4
    data.fromfile(f, size // 4)
data[2] = new_value
# use data.tofile(g) to write the data back to a new file g
```

Comment: *see comment on hochl's answer*

Answer (score 2):

You could install the  numpy module, which is often used for scientific computing.

read_data = numpy.fromfile(file=id, dtype=numpy.uint32)

Then access the data at the desired location and make your changes.

Comment: *see comment on hochl's answer*

Answer (score 1):

The following is just a demonstration for you to understand what really happens when the four bytes are converted into an integer.
Suppose you have a number: 15213

```
Decimal: 15213
Binary: 0011 1011 0110 1101
Hex: 3 B 6 D
```

On little-endian systems (i.e x86 machines), this number can be represented using a length-4 bytearray as: `b"\x6d\x3b\x00\x00"` or `b"m;\x00\x00"` when you print it on the screen, to convert the four bytes into an integer, we simply do a bit of base conversion, which in this case, is:

```
sum(n*(256**i) for i,n in enumerate(b"\x6d\x3b\x00\x00"))
```

This gives you the result: 15213