# Converting Epoch DateTime to Byte Array in Python

Tags: python, epoch

I am trying to convert epoch datetime to byte array in python
but it is coming as 10 Byte, it should come in 4 Byte.

```
from time import time
curTime = int(time.time())
b = bytearray(str(curTime))
len(b)                 #comming as 10
```

Can any one help where i am wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are converting the string representation of the timestamp, not the integer.

What you need is this function:

struct.pack_into(fmt, buffer, offset, v1, v2, ...)
It's documented at http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html near the top.

```
import struct
from time import time
curTime = int(time())
b = struct.pack(">i", curTime)
len(b)    # 4
```

Stolen from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7921876/2442434